# Have CodeIgniter Ignore a Directory

Tags: php, codeigniter

I just started to play around with the new editor CKEditor, and i’m liking it alot.  The one issue i’m trying to solve is configure the editor for file uploads.

Like with FCKeditor the uploader and file browser are included in the plugin.  When I try to launch the browser or uploader, CI tells me the file is not there.

What is happening is CI is launching and running through its code.  I would rather have CI just ignore the library all together.  I have a feeling you can do this with .htaccess but my skills with Rewrites are limited.  Any help would be great!

Here is my folder structure:
- CI Directory
   - System
   - Assets
      - css
      - images
      - js
         - ckeditor (This is the directory i would like to have CI Ignore)

Comment: RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]

Answer (score 1):

try to change it to...

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

i have use this configuration for a long time with no problems.